# Unknown class <SmartTileWithStar> in kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

This is based on this  tutorial: [Image List](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/image-list/index.html)

I have created a folder called "cats", inside  this folder i have  three images and I want to display them on the screen with python.
Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 3
        row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
        row_force_default: True
        adaptive_height: True
        padding: dp(4), dp(4)
        spacing: dp(4)

        SmartTileWithStar:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-1.jpg"

        SmartTileWithStar:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-2.jpg"

        SmartTileWithStar:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-.jpg"
'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

But when I run this code, I am getting this error:

```
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <SmartTileWithStar>
```

Maybe the class name is changed? I tried to find more information about this error but have gotten no result. If it is custom  class, then it should be mentioned on the site, could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

i have done a little research and foind following solution :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
# from kivymd.uix.imagelist import MDSmartTile
KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 3
        row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
        row_force_default: True
        adaptive_height: True
        padding: dp(4), dp(4)
        spacing: dp(4)

        MDSmartTile:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-1.jpg"
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "heart-outline"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                on_release: self.icon = "heart" if self.icon == "heart-outline" else "heart-outline"

        MDSmartTile:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-2.jpg"
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "heart-outline"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                on_release: self.icon = "heart" if self.icon == "heart-outline" else "heart-outline"

        MDSmartTile:
            stars: 5
            source: "cats/cat-3.jpg"
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "heart-outline"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                on_release: self.icon = "heart" if self.icon == "heart-outline" else "heart-outline"
'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

result of this code  is :
[image]

only one thing is that i  dont know how to rate,  only  heart caption is added, if anyone has  idea please share it with me